# Solving a system of two differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Given the following system of two differential equations.

$$\frac{dx}{dt}=\alpha(y-x)$$

$$\frac{dy}{dt}=\alpha(x-y)$$

Reduce the above system of two differential equation to a system of one dimension differential equation and solve the resulting one-dimensional differential equation.

What i tried

I tried relating both the system of differential equation, $\frac{dx}{dt}=-\frac{dy}{dt}$ Then integrating the following expression i got, $x(t)=-y(t)+c$.
Am i correct. Could anyone please explain. Thanks

Comment: How do u get the  one-dimensional differential equation first?

Answer (score 0):

You can write the system this way
$$
\frac{d}{dt}
\begin{pmatrix}
x \\
y
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
-\alpha & \alpha \\
\alpha& -\alpha
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
x \\
y
\end{pmatrix}
$$
It then is possible to interpret this system as one vector equation, which has one vector variable, however that vector is two dimensional, which does not fit your wording.
$$
\dot{u} = A u
$$

Comment: So i must reduced the system of equations to a matrix form ? And the matrix form is considered a one-dimension system. Then next i must solve the matrix, by getting the eigenvalues/eigenvectors etc?

Comment: You should check your wording, I believe there is some mix up between variables and dimensions.